# Texas instruments Nspire cx ii-t IT access problem with tilp2

Tags: texas-instruments

I recently had to buy a ti nspire but I am facing a problem communicating with the calculator via my PC while tilp detects my ti-83!, I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 and I installed Tilp2 via the bach script but I get this error at launch:

```
Msg: failed to open the USB device.
Cause: Check that the USB cable is plugged in and that the calculator is turned ON! Also, check libusb and usbfs for valid permissions.
```

I have this displayed in the console and I have not been able to resolve the problems.

```
(tilp:461281): ticables-WARNING **: 20:18:17.115: no devices found!

tilp-INFO: 20:18:17.115: Opening cable DirectLink on port #1 to communicate with calculator Nspire

(tilp:461281): ticables-CRITICAL **: 20:18:17.115: ticables_get_model(NULL)

(tilp:461281): ticables-CRITICAL **: 20:18:17.115: ticables_get_port(NULL)
ticables-INFO: 20:18:17.115: Check for libusb support:
ticables-INFO: 20:18:17.115:     usb support: available.
ticables-INFO: 20:18:17.115: Check for libusb usability:
ticables-INFO: 20:18:17.115:     usb filesystem (/dev/bus/usb/): mounted

(tilp:461281): ticables-WARNING **: 20:18:17.115: no devices found!

ticalcs-INFO: 20:18:17.115: Cable DirectLink port #1 attached
tilp-INFO: 20:18:17.115: Msg: failed to open the USB device.
Cause: Check that the USB cable is plugged in and that the calculator is turned ON! Also, check libusb and usbfs for valid permissions.
System: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno = 11)


(tilp:461281): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 20:18:17.154: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
```